# Sending a custom TCP packet

Tags: networking, tcp-ip, netcat

I am building a program that extracts transport layer data from packets, I want to test it but I couldn't find a way to specify TCP flags using netcat.

Is there a tool that does this for Linux, or is there a way to do that with netcat?

thanks

Comment: Looks like your question more relevant for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: `apt-cache search packet` gives many results, but `bittwist - libpcap based Ethernet packet generator`, `icmpush - ICMP packet builder`, `libnetpacket-perl - modules to manipulate network packets at the protocol level`, `packeth - Ethernet packet generator`, 
`packit - network injection and capture tool` and several other packages seem to apply. Learn about these packages at https://packages.ubuntu.com/